# How to switch a widget's Animation transition in Kivy

Tags: python, animation, kivy, transition

#### Summary:

I would like to test all the possible transitions of Kivy's `Animation` function.

In my code, I call a method to switch the buttons' animations. The method is successfully called because I used `print` to confirm the change; however, the buttons' transitions don't accept the change. They keep using the first animation but do not take on the next animation in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from random import random
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock


class LittleButtons(Button):

    transition = 'in_back'
    dur = 2
    num = 0

    def change_transition(self):

        list = ['in_back','in_bounce','in_circ','in_cubic','in_elastic','in_expo','in_out_back',
                'in_out_bounce','in_out_cubic','in_out_elastic','in_out_expo',
                'in_out_quad','in_out_quart','in_out_quint','in_out_sine','in_quad','in_quart',
                'in_quint','in_sine','linear','out_back','out_bounce','out_circ','out_cubic',
                'out_elastic','out_expo','out_quad','out_quart','out_quint','out_sine']

        self.num += 1
        self.transition = list[self.num]
        self.reup()
        print(self.transition)

        if self.num == len(list) - 1:
            self.num = -1

    def reup(self, *args):

        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        anim = Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()},
                         duration = self.dur, t = self.transition)
        anim.start(self)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(LittleButtons, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.width = random() * (Window.width / 20)
        self.height = random() * (Window.width / 20)
        self.background_color = [0,0,0,.05]

        Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()},
                  duration = self.dur).start(self)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reup, self.dur)

KV = Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

Screen:
    FloatLayout:
        on_parent:
            (lambda ltext: [self.add_widget(Factory.LittleButtons(text=ltext)) for i in range (150)])('hi!')
        LittleButtons:
            id: base
        Button:
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size:self.size
            on_release:
                base.change_transition()
""")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KV

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: It works for me correctly: https://imgur.com/a/zYourkg

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for checking. The app will open and have the first transition work perfectly; however, the app will not have another transitions by clicking the background button > ```on_release:
                base.change_transition()```
The only way it works is if stop the app, copy and paste the transition names into `transition = ` and start the app again.

Comment: I recommend reading your question again since what you indicate in your comment does not agree with what you describe in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, but not doing what you expect. Your `on_release` calls `base.change_transition()`, which refer to the `base` id. That `id` is the one `LittleButtons` in your `KV` string that is not built by the `on_parent` event. The animation transition of that one `LittleButtons` is successfully modified, but the others are unaffected. Also, that particular `LittleButtons` is unseen, since the big `Button` hides it. So, you are successfully changing the transition of one `LittleButtons`, but it doesn't show.

Comment: Ah, I see. How would I change it to have all the buttons effected?

Comment: One way would be to create a class that extends `FloatLayout` and use it to replace the `FloatLayout` in your `KV`. Provide an `id: base` for that new class and implement  a `change_transition()` method in it. That method would have a loop that changes the transition for each of its `LittleButtons` children and then calls the `reup()` method for each.

Comment: That makes sense. Although, each button must have its unique id, rather than just having all the ids as `base`, right? Out of curiosity, how would each get their own id? Would I do something like `base1`, `base2`, `...` with a +1 loop?

Comment: They cannot all have the same `id`, and each having their own unique `id` wouldn't help much. If the `Widget` containing all the `LittleButtons` has an id, you can have a `change_transition()` method of that container. That method could loop through the `children` list of the container or use the `walk()` method to visit each of the `LittleButtons`. See the [Widget documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) for more info.